# Appended comments but they show up above the content instead of below

Tags: php, comments, comments-template

I am trying to append a comments template to the end of the flash object in this plugin file. Below is the full code. To pinpoint exactly where I added the comments template, please refer to [this pastebin](http://pastebin.com/KYeWXAaA). The appended comments template is on line 164. For some reason, even though I appended it, the comments template shows up above the flash object rather than below. Does anyone have a clue how I can solve this?

```
<?php

require_once('ismobile.php');

/******************************************************************
/* Build Player
******************************************************************/
class Player {

    var $width, $height;



    public function buildPlayer( $profileid = 1, $videoid = 1, $autodetect = 1 ) {
        global $wpdb;       

        $profile      = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."allvideogallery_profiles WHERE id=".$profileid);     
        $this->width  = $profile->width;
        $this->height = $profile->height;

        if( isset($_GET['slg']) && $autodetect == 1 ) {
            $slug    = $_GET['slg'];
            $video   = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."allvideogallery_videos WHERE slug='$slug'");
            $videoid = $video->id;
        } else {
            $video   = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."allvideogallery_videos WHERE  id=".$videoid);
        }   

        if($video->type == 'thirdparty') {
            $result    = '<div style="width:' . $this->width . 'px; height:' . $this->height . 'px;">';
            $result   .= $video->thirdparty;
            $result   .= '</div>';
        } else {
            $arr_params = array();  
            $custpage   = ( $profile->custom_page_url ) ? $profile->custom_page_url : $this->curPageURL();
            if( isset($_GET['catid']) ) {
                $arr_params['catid'] = $_GET['catid'];
            }
            if( isset($_GET['sort']) ) {
                $arr_params['sort'] = $_GET['sort'];
            }       

            $videosids=$video->id;
$imgad_query=mysql_query("select * from ".$wpdb->prefix."allvideogallery_videos WHERE published='1' and id='$videosids'");
$imgad_row=mysql_fetch_array($imgad_query);
$imgads=$imgad_row['img_ads'];
$text_ads1=$imgad_row['text_ads'];
$ads_links1=$imgad_row['ads_links'];
$imgad_link='<img src="'.$imgads.'" alt="" >';

            $flashvars = 'base='.get_option('siteurl').'&wp=1&vid='.$videoid.'&pid='.$profileid.'&page='.urlencode( @add_query_arg($arr_params, $custpage) );
            $detect    = new IsMobile();            
            $result    = $detect->isMobile() ? $this->gethtmlplayer( $profile, $video ) : $this->getflashplayer( $profile, $flashvars, $ads_links1, $imgads, $text_ads1 );  




        }       

        $this->updatehits( $video->slug );

        $cust_class = ( $profile->custom_player_class ) ? $profile->custom_player_class : 'avs_player';

        $output  = '<style type="text/css">' . "\n";
        $output .= $profile->player_css . "\n";
        $output .= '.video_div
{
float:left;
width:100%;
}
.ad_text
{
float:left; 
/*width:472px;*/
margin:301px 15px 0px 15px;
  background-color:#ffffff;
  border:1px solid black;
  opacity:0.6;
  filter:alpha(opacity=60); /* For IE8 and earlier */
  color:#000000;
    padding:5px 6px;
    position:absolute;
 z-index: 10000;
 display:block;
 font-size: 12px;
 bottom:63px;
}
.ad_text img
{
max-width:90%;
}
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#clickme").click(function() {
  $("#book").hide();
});
});
</script>
' . "\n";




        $output .= '<div class="'.$cust_class.'" style="width:'.$this->width.'px;">' . "\n";
        if($profile->title) {
            $output .= '<div class="title">'.$video->title.'</div>' . "\n";
        }
        if($profile->category) {
            $output .= '<div class="category"><strong>Category : </strong>'.$video->category.'</div>' . "\n";
        }
        if($profile->hits) {
            $output .= '<div class="hits"><strong>Hits : </strong>'.$video->hits.'</div>' . "\n";
        }
        $output .= '<div style="clear:both;"></div>' . "\n";
        $output .= $result . "\n";
        if($video->description) {
            $output .= '<div class="description">'.$video->description.'</div>' . "\n";
        }
        $output .= '</div>' . "\n";

        return $output;
    }



    public function getflashplayer( $profile, $flashvars, $ads_links1, $imgads, $text_ads1 ) {
        global $allvideogallery_plugin_dir;

        if(!empty($imgads)) {  $show_ads1='<img src="'.$imgads.'" alt="">'; } else { $show_ads1=$text_ads1;  }
        $get_ads_width=$this->width;
        $get_ads_width1=$get_ads_width-30;

        $siteurl = get_option('siteurl');
        $src     = $siteurl . '/wp-content/plugins/' . $allvideogallery_plugin_dir . '/player.swf?random=' . rand();


        $result .= '<div class="video_div" style="width:' . $this->width . 'px; height:'.$this->height.'px;"> <div style="width:100%; height:100%; position:relative;">';
        if(!empty($imgads) || !empty($text_ads1)) {
         $result .= '<div class="ad_text" id="book" style="width:'.$get_ads_width1.'px;" >';
         $result .= '<p style="float:right; width:4%; margin:0px;">';
        $result .= '<a href="#" id="clickme" style="float:right; line-height:0px;"><img src="'.site_url().'/wp-content/plugins/all-video-gallery/close_icon.png"></a></p>';
        //$result .= '';
        $result .= '<a href="'.$ads_links1.'">'.$show_ads1.'</a>';

        $result .= '</div>';
        }

        $result .= '<object id="player" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" name="player" width="' . $this->width . '" height="' . $this->height . '">';
        $result .= '<param name="movie" value="' . $src . '" />';
        $result .= '<param name="wmode" value="opaque" />';
        $result .= '<param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />';
        $result .= '<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />';
        $result .= '<param name="flashvars" value="' . $flashvars . '" />';
        $result .= '<div><object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="' . $src . '" width="' . $this->width . '" height="' . $this->height . '">';
        $result .= '<param name="movie" value="' . $src . '" />';
        $result .= '<param name="wmode" value="opaque" />';
        $result .= '<param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />';
        $result .= '<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />';
        $result .= '<param name="flashvars" value="' . $flashvars . '" />';
        $result .= '</object></div>';
        $result .= '</object></div></div>';
        $result .= comments_template(); //Append the comments template to the result

        return $result;
    }

    public function gethtmlplayer( $profile, $video ) {
        if($video->type == 'youtube') {
            $url_string = parse_url($video->video, PHP_URL_QUERY);
            parse_str($url_string, $args);
            $result  = '<iframe title="YouTube Video Player" width="'.$this->width.'" height="'.$this->height.'" ';
            $result .= 'src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$args['v'].'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
        } else {
            $preview = $video->preview ? 'poster="' . $video->preview . '"' : '';
            $result  = '<video onclick="this.play();" width="'.$this->width.'" height="'.$this->height.'" '.$preview.' controls>';
            $result .= '<source src="'.$video->video.'" />';
            $result .= '</video><br />';
            $result .= comments_template(); //Append the comments template to the result
        }

        return $result;
    }

    function curPageURL() {
        $pageURL = 'http'; 

        if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) {if($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on'){$pageURL .= "s";}} 
        $pageURL .= "://"; 
        if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") { 
            $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; 
        } else { 
            $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; 
        } 

        return $pageURL;
    }

    function updatehits( $slug ) {
        global $wpdb;

        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix."allvideogallery_videos";
        $video = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE slug='$slug'");        
        $count = ($video) ? $video->hits + 1 : 1;
        $video->hits = $count;

        $wpdb->update($table_name, array('hits' => $video->hits), array('id' => $video->id));
    }

}

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using comments_template which prints out the comments and returns nothing you need to capture the comments template so try this:

```
function get_comments_template(){
    ob_start();
    comments_template();
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

and change this line:

```
$result .= comments_template(); //Append the comments template to the result
```

to

```
$result .= get_comments_template();
```